# Are we allowed to create the private variable in case of auto implemented properties?

Tags: c#

Suppose we use auto implemented properties.

Example:

```
public class Test {
    public int val1 { get; set; }
}
```

Above code automatically generates a private variable called: `private int val1`

My question is that what happens if we explicitly declare this variable above the auto implemented property code?

Example:

```
public class Test {
   private int val1;

   public int val1 { get; set; }
}
```

Are both examples equivalent?

Comment: Did you try it? Did the second one compile at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry Nachiket but you are wrong. The backing field of the automatically implemented property val1 is not called val1. You could simply test that using a decompiler, like ildasm. Please look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Secondly, you cannot declare a property and a private variable with the same name. So your second example isn't correct. Try to type it in the visual studio and you will see the corresponding error message.

Answer (score 3):

The backing field created by compiler is not named `val1`. Name of that variable is created in a way it's impossible to interrupt your code, so you shouldn't worry about that.

Backing field name is generated in a way which makes it incorrect identifier in C#, but is OK for CLR specification. That's why it will never interrupt your code.

That's why following code compiles just fine:

```
class Test
{
    private int _val1;
    private int val1;
    public int Val1 { get; set; }
}
```

And if you look at IL generated for class like that, you'll see that backing field for `Val1` will be:

```
.field private int32 '<Val1>k__BackingField'
```

`<Val1>k_BackingField` is incorrect identifier in C#, but is correct in CLR.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd code snippet will not compile due to duplicate member names. The property name conflicts with the name of the field you declared.

Answer (score 1):

The second won't compile, I believe, due to duplicate names. The generated member variable won't conflict with any new member variables you create, their complier assures that. You can do something like this, if this is what you want:

```
public class test
{
   Public int val1{ get; private set;}
}
```

i.e. make the setter private. But it's not clear what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Your second code snippet will not compile.If you change the property or field name, it will compile.And they become completely different things.Compiler will still create a *backing-field* for your *auto-implemented* property.So there will be no relationship  between your property and field.